# Problem with configure - cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: debian, gcc, configure

I want install [Argos 0.5](http://www.few.vu.nl/argos/?page=0)  to Debian 3.12.6-2 (2013-12-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux. I had to install gcc 3.4  because Argos call for it. Now I have gcc 3.4 and gcc 4.8.2-2 too. Problem is that `./configure` script gives this error:

```
The error log from compiling the libSDL test is:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: ARGOS requires SDL or Cocoa for graphical output
To build ARGOS without graphical output configure with --disable-gfx-check
Note that this will disable all output from the virtual graphics card.
```

I have installed libsdl and Cocoa with apt-get. But I have the same problem still. If I search libgcc: `find /usr/ -name libgcc*` I get this output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1.0.3
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s_32.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_s_32.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/32/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_eh.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a
/usr/lib/ure/lib/libgcc3_uno.so
/usr/share/doc/libgcc-4.7-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgcc1
/usr/share/doc/libgcc-4.8-dev
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libgcc1
```

How can I solve this problem?

I have tried compile this simple program with gcc-3.4.

```
// program.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 printf("Hello, world!\n");
 return 0;
}
```

And I get tis output:

```
gcc-3.4 program.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I use gcc 4.8.2 everything is ok.

Comment: How do you know it's using the correct version of gcc?

Comment: The obvious question is - how do you know you are compiling using gcc 3.4? By default, build systems will use the default gcc, which clearly is not 3.4. This may be configurable in your build system - probably a Makefile. I suggest you check this.

Comment: Thanks for replies, configure script writes: 
/opt/argos-0.5.0/src# ./configure --enable-net-tracker
WARNING: "gcc" looks like gcc 4.x
Looking for gcc 3.x
Found "gcc-3.4"
So I thing that this script found correct gcc version.

Comment: Any other idea please? :-(

Comment: Did you install 3.4 from source? It is not longer available in recent Debian. If so, this might be a configuration issue. If you want to debug it, try a simple program that tries to link against `-lgcc_s`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks, no I have installed it with this way http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu. What simple program do you think please?

Comment: Anything at all will probably work. Even a hello world program. You just want to see if the linker will find the library.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you. I tried compile very simple program with gcc-3.4 and I got the same error. I added it to my first post. Compilation with current version gcc 4.8.2 was ok. So any idea what I can do please?

Comment: I have tried install gcc 3.x from source but it does not possible. I get some error allways. Do you know about any 3.x version that would be compile on Debian 7 without errors and problems please?

Comment: @Mato Ok, it does sound like your compiler is misconfigured. Can you specify the exact method you used to install the gcc 3.x? Above you just linked to the question on AU, but that question has several replies. Note that installing a non-multiarch version of gcc 3.4 on a multiarch machine will not work. Having said that, the version you have installed might be multiarch. I'm not sure. Please also state your Debian version (if you are running Debian). You can give the output of `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have used practice from http://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu post 6. My version is: 
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux testing (jessie)
Release:        testing
Codename:       jessie

Comment: Hi Mato. It looks like you have enough rep to use chat, so can you ping me in the unix.sx chat room? It would be a better place than writing in these comments.

Comment: @FaheemMitha ok, now I am there.

Comment: Have anyone any other idea please?